# Column from selected Datagrid

Tags: c#, datagrid

I have code that returns me the selected row from a datagrid.
Now i want to have the value of the 3th column.
The code I have below already gives me the selected row

```
private void BandGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var row_list = GetDataGridRows(BandGrid);
                foreach (DataGridRow single_row in row_list)
                {
                    if (single_row.IsSelected == true)
                    {

                    }
                }

            }
            catch { }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your DataGrid has an underlying data structure and you are not using datagridview, each row represents an object usually in a list of objects.  You can just cast the selected row to the object's Type and pull the field of the cell you want.  Also you don't have to loop through each one in the list.  SelectedItem will have what you want.

**Edited**

```
private void BandGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Band single_row = (Band)BandGrid.SelectedItem;

        string cellValue = single_row.Picture;

    }
```

**Edited End**

If you have multi select feature on you may need to pull all iterating through SelectedItems.  Note: don't make changes to the items in the foreach loop this will cause errors.  You will need to make a copy of the data if you need to change the data.

```
 private void dataGrid1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      listCells = new List<string>();
       foreach(MyClass single_row in BandGrid.SelectedItems)
        {

              //do something with the object
             listCells.add( single_row.Picture);
        } 

    }
```

Example program.  This sets the `DataSource` for the grid to `List<MyClass>` and every time the selection is changed `textbox1` displays data in column c from the selected row.

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
      public class MyClass
      {
       public int a { get; set; }
       public int b { get; set; }
       public int c { get; set; }
       public int d { get; set; }
      }
      public MainWindow()
      {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyClass obj;
        List<MyClass> bind = new List<MyClass>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            obj = new MyClass();
            obj.a = i;
            obj.b = 2*i;
            obj.c = 3*i;
            obj.d = 4*i;
            bind.Add(obj);
        }

        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = bind;
    }

    private void dataGrid1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        textBox1.Text = ((MyClass)dataGrid1.SelectedItem).c.ToString();



    }
}
```

Here's the xaml

```
<Window x:Class="yo.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="116,116,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="344" SelectionChanged="dataGrid1_SelectionChanged" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="87,41,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: if i change myclass to string i get an InvalidCastException. Also, what is yourField?

Comment: what data are you displaying?  Myclass should be the specific class your datagrid displays.  So you should have a source List<MyClass>.  yourfield is a field value like int, string, float of MyClass.

Comment: I have this now

private void BandGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Bands single_row = (Bands)BandGrid.SelectedItem;

            var cell = single_row.yourField;
        } 

I still don't know what to do about yourField. I need column 3 and i can't read from the code that i'm getting column 3

Comment: Now you are working with an instance of the class of type `Band` `single_row`.  What does column 3 represent in the class Bands?  That will be yourfield.

Comment: got this now

Bands single_row = (Bands)BandGrid.SelectedItem;
            var cell = single_row.ToString();

Error on SelectedItem cannot convert to Band

Comment: Post a copy of the class Bands, exactly what column 3 is and the type it should be.

Comment: posted it in a word file. https://www.dropbox.com/s/hsv6bwoi2s16hqc/Word%20Band.docx

Comment: Sorry I changed it on my answer above.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! Here have an upvote ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       var selectedValue  = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
}
```

Comment: BandGrid does not contain a definition for 'SelectedRow'

Comment: is it your web application or window ?